# How many friends of friends of friends?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to determine how many second degree (friends of friends), and third degree (friends of friends of friends) a typical individual has based on the current number of friends he or she possesses and the density of a network. Is this correct for determining friends of friends?

Friends of Friends = Friends * (Average number of friends * 1 - network density)

How would I determine the number of friends of friends of friends?

Comment: Seriously, couldn't you just ask them? A rough estimate from the real world would make things easier. Where is this going? Do you have a large no. of friends from which to choose? What's the context here?

Comment: I'm trying to apply this calculation to any typical member of a large network so asking isn't possible. For instance, how many friends of friends of friends does a Facebook use have based on the number of friends they have. Page 21 [link](http://www.pewinternet.org/~/media//Files/Reports/2012/PIP_Facebook%20users_2.3.12.pdf) here lays the groundwork for determining the second degree. I'm now trying to determine the third degree.

Answer (score 1):

The first challenge is a definition:  if A,B, and C are all friends of each other, are A and C friends of friends (because of B) or not (because they are already friends)?  The second challenge is that your friends are much more likely to be friends of each other than friends of somebody you are not friends with.  You need some parameter that measures the correlation between friendships.

If you ignore the correlation and say your friends are equally likely to be friends with anybody in the world, it is quite unlikely that any of them are friends of each other.  Then the first challenge doesn't matter, and Friends of Friends=Friends*(Average number of friends-1) where the -1 comes because your friends spent one of their friendships on you.  Again, Friends of Friends of Friends=Friends*(Average number of friends-1)^2  This breaks down when the power gets high enough that there is a significant amount of overlap.  Say you have 30 friends and the average is 20.  Then you would expect to have 570 friends of friends, 10830 friends of friends of friends.  Even at the next level, with 205770 friends^4, you expect to see overlap if the friends are randomly selected from the world population-there are over 20 billion pairs, so the likelihood of a match is high.

Comment: Not double-counting the overlap is really the crux of the question. In [this paper](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474601/how-many-friends-of-friends-of-friends) on page 21, they begin to mention how to adjust for this (the 12%). How would I adjust for this in the third degree?

Comment: Excerpt from paper:

The average user has 245 friends, and their average friend has 359 friends and are interconnected such that 12% of a user’s friends friends are already their friends.

This would lead us to believe that the average user can reach 77400 people through their friends and their friends of friends (calculated as 245 *(359*1-.12)).

Comment: I realize the link was broken in the above comment. Here it is: [link](http://www.pewinternet.org/~/media//Files/Reports/2012/PIP_Facebook%20users_2.3.12.pdf)